# Certain and inseperable results: is the phrasing "Make for yourself inevitabilities reality" valid?

Tags: grammaticality

`Make effort towards your goals, which at present seem improbable, until they become inevitable.`

I wish to mean this, is "Make for yourself inevitabilities reality." valid? I would understand it when spoken with a pause after "inevitabilities", as in 'these things which are inevitable, make them for yourself'.

I'm a native speaker of English, though I find myself using odd sentence constructions, would this be understood by others?

Comment: No, it's not.   ..

Comment: The original sentence is fine (if you accept the philosophy).  I can't make heads or tails of the rest of what you said.

Answer (score 1):

I think this sentence is grammatical, if structurally ambiguous and semantically weird.

Just consider that the following sentence is grammatical (to my ear):

- "Make for yourself that empty cup a full one."

The poster's sentence does ***not*** (on its intended interpetation) have two direct objects, as some have suggested. Rather, the verb "make" takes a *small clause*, consisting of a subject (in this case "inevitabilities") and a predicate (in this case "reality"). It is no different from "make" taking a small clause in the sentence "The witch made the white cat black".

It seems no different in principle from the imperative: "Make, for yourself, your dreams reality." (The commas help here but aren't necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not valid, because you have two direct objects and one needs to be indirect.

You are acting on *inevitabilities* (DO) to turn them into *reality* (IO). An indirect object is normally indicated by a preposition, like *into*. Some verbs don't need a preposition, and the relationship is indicated purely by position; that's not the case here because *for yourself* is getting in the way.

The word *inevitabilities* is wrong, because that is already effectively reality. You probably want the word you used in the question, *improbabilities,* or, more idiomatically, *what is improbable.*

*Make* is grammatical (once everything else is sorted), and is one of the verbs which doesn't normally need a preposition if everything is in the right order, but *Turn [into]* would be more idiomatic.

> Turn what is improbable into reality.
>   Make what is improbable reality.

The *for yourself* is really problematic. It doesn't fit very well into the first sentence, and in the second sentence it should qualify *reality:*

> Make what is improbable reality for yourself.

Perhaps the reason that *for yourself* doesn't really fit is that if something is real, it's real. For everyone, not just you. It's awkward because it implies that your reality is experienced only by you, which is a pathological psychosis. Just leave it out and change everyone's reality, however improbable it might be.

The sentence as given has the air of being a literal translation from another language. Sentences where word-order is important, or especially if they use *make* or *do,* are tricky and a word-for-word translation will almost always fail. The cognate forms of *make* and *do* in other languages (such as the German *machen* and *tun*) are false friends.

Comment: As an afterthought here, "Make what is improbable reality" can be misconstrued as "Make something which is an improbable reality," where the *reality* has the adjective *improbable,* rather than *what*. Using *turn [into]* avoids that ambiguity.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you answering a proofreading question? Is there a linguistic phenomenon that interests you (I admit these often escape me)? (Well, I see from your answer that there is one. Duh.) Please don't misunderstand; I favor the freedom of users to answer what they will, but how is this not encouraging proofreading questions when a mod answers them?

Comment: @medica I'm feeling magnanimous; the linguistic phenomenon of why *inevitabilities reality* doesn't really work here does interest me. Perhaps I haven't explained that very well though. It would be possible to turn the question into a not-proof-reading question reasonably easily if the OP were to say something like "I translated [...] from [whichever language it was] and came up with ... but it seems awkward; is *for yourself* in the wrong place? Is it *inevitabilities* which is unidiomatic?"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would edit the OP's question myself if I could to change it into not-proofreading. I'll think on it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

"Is 'Make for yourself inevitabilities reality' valid?" Not so much. **"Make even your improbable goals become inevitable realities"** might be a good slogan for what you describe.